# how to change the Model field value with logic to time

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have a model named Quote

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    # date_validity will have persistent data like this 2023-11-30 15:00
    date_validity = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    quote_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=150, default='active')
```

So I need to set quote_status expired if data_validity meets the current time, If validity is 2 days later from now then the quote should expire if validity time is over.

How can I manage this automatically? As far as I know self.save() method does not trigger automatically. So any suggestions to solve this?

I guess this is not possible until we call a function periodically like with celery. Is there other way to do?

Comment: Please use a `DateTimeField`, *not* a `CharField` to store a timestamp.

Comment: Does DateTimeField will accept the date-time formate like this 2023-11-30 15:00 ?

Comment: @atopabelladona: it is normally parsed through a form which will accept all formats in the [**`DATETIME_INPUT_FORMAT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS), so the form will accept `2023-11-30 15:00` yes.

Comment: @atopabelladona
yes. 2022-04-11 18:47:00+03 it even can have a timezone if you set it in settings.py

Comment: Ok, thanks, Willem, and Kusko, I'm definitely going to follow this, But can u give me the idea of how to change the status if date_validity gets over?

Comment: Without using any task manager like celery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use a [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField), *not* a `CharField` to store a timestamp. As for the status, you should *not* store this in the model. You can determine this when necessary, for example with a property, or with a [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to check the status.

Indeed, you can define a model with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import timedelta

class Quote(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def status(self):
        return 'active' if self.created >= now()-timdelta(days=2) else 'expired'
```

and you can for example retrieve all *acive* and *expired* quotes with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now
from datetime import timedelta

active = Quote.objects.filter(created__gte=Now()-timedelta(days=2))
expired = Quote.objects.filter(created__lt=Now()-timedelta(days=2))
```